# QDataWidgetMapper

Tags: c++, qt

Как в диалоговом окне сделать кнопку которая будет добавлять данные из диалогового окна `neworder.cpp` в базу из этих трех полей(lineedit)?

Листинг `mainwindow.cpp`:

```
model =  new QSqlTableModel(this,baze);
model->setTable("orders");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
new_o = new newOrder();
new_o->setParent(this,Qt::Window);
new_o->setModel(model);
```

редактирование при дабл клике

```
void MainWindow::on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{

    new_o->mapper->setCurrentModelIndex(index);
    new_o->show();
}
```

Вызываю окно добавление данных

```
void MainWindow::on_addOrderButton_clicked()
{
    new_o->show();
}
```

файл окна neworder.cpp

```
    mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
    mapper->setSubmitPolicy(QDataWidgetMapper::ManualSubmit);

}

void newOrder::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *model)
{

    mapper->setModel(model);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->adressLineEdit,1);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->orderTextEdit,2,"plainText");
    mapper->addMapping(ui->phoneLineEdit,3);

}

void newOrder::on_applyButton_clicked()
{
    mapper->submit();

}
```

Comment: Если `newOrder` - это и есть диалоговое окно, то `on_applyButton_clicked()` и есть искомый слот, который по `submit()` и добавит данные в модель, а затем в БД. Так в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: все верно.  сейчас работает только для редактирования. А мне нужна кнопка которая создаст новое поле в базе. С новыми данными. Как ее сделать ) используя QDataWidgetMapper это реально или проще 3 лайн эдита сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
void newOrder::on_insertButton_clicked() {
    const int row = model->rowCount();
    model->insertRow(row);
    mapper->setCurrentModelIndex(model->index(row,0));
}
```

**Дополнение**

Чтобы указатель на модель не хранить отдельно, лучше так:

```
void newOrder::on_insertButton_clicked() {
    if(mapper->model() == Q_NULLPTR) return;

    const int row = mapper->model()->rowCount();
    mapper->model()->insertRow(row);
    mapper->setCurrentModelIndex(mapper->model()->index(row,0));
}
```

Comment: Мир не без добрых людей. )))))